# cat /proc/pid/cmdline hangs (no cgroups, no nfs or network fs, no memory issues)

Tags: kernel, ubuntu-22.04

We are a bit stumped.
Once in a while `ps`/`w` hang forever (at least an hour) on our server, and it is on reading `/proc/pid/cmdline` for a process (happend twice today, verified with `strace cat` directly on `cmdline`).
Only things that fixes it is a `kill -9`.

There are no containers running on the server, and no OOM conditions (actually >3TB memory free). No NFS or other network filesystems.

Running `5.19.0-1019-aws #20~22.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Thu Jan 26 11:24:23 UTC 2023 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`, Ubuntu 22, its a high core-count and high memory NUMA system.

The offending processes are at S or Z states during the hang.

We read the following but it didn't help us:

- https://rachelbythebay.com/w/2014/10/27/ps/
- https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=8520045

ChatGPT4 is stumped to.

Any ideas?
Thanks!

Comment: Do you have a process that uses `fanotify`? If it is buggy it might not process permission events properly leaving the call waiting indefinitely...

Comment: Thanks for you reply, no process use fanotify.

Comment: Confirming, I have this too on NixOS 23.05. Same in strace, all programs that read the `cmdline` hang (e.g. `ps`, `htop`, and so on). `kill -9` immediately fixes it.

Comment: Potentially related: http://rachelbythebay.com/w/2014/10/27/ps/